# Is it safe to call dismissModalViewControllerAnimated within a modal view on iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is it safe to call dismissModalViewControllerAnimated within a modal view? or should it be called from the controller that initiated the modal view? If so how would I program that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation does not make it clear what's going on (e.g. is it safe to do `[self.parentViewController.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO]`?), but in my testing you can dismiss the modal VC from either itself or its parent:

- From either VC, you can do `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO]`
- From the parent VC, you can do `[self.modalViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO]`
- From the modal VC, you can do `[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO]`